# Type safety warning when using synchronizedList

Tags: java, eclipse

I define a class member as below :

```
private static List abc = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

But Eclipse gives me the warning :

```
Type safety: Unchecked invocation synchronizedList(ArrayList) of the generic method synchronizedList(List<T>) of type Collections
```

Is there another way to write this declaration statement to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a raw type warning because you are using a `new ArrayList()` initializer without specifying the generic type.

Since Java 5 [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) are introduced in Java.

They allow type abstraction and type safety.

Your warning will go away when you specify it as such:

```
private static List<MyType> abc = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<MyType>());
```

... where `MyType` is the generic type you want for that `List`.

Comment: thanks. I found a great answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/2105986 as well to understand raw types.

Comment: That SO answer is somewhat biased, though very well written. To say that raw types should **never** be used is to ignore the cost of type parameters and to assume the code always needs to know the type. I've run into plenty of situations where the type was not needed, especially in small contexts (like within a single method or test). The answer also presumes that we always want/need the "big brother" compiler to watch out for us, which again isn't *always* the case, IME.

Comment: @E-Riz You've piqued my interest. I've never heard of type parameters having a cost. Do you mind explaining that further or sharing some situations where that might be the case?

Comment: The cost is syntactic, and repetition. If I don't actually care about the type of, for example, a `List`, having to declare a type (eg, `<Object>`) clutters the code; and it has to be done in *two* places (the declaration and the constructor call), even more clutter. Not to mention the fact that the syntax for type parameters is unique from the rest of the language. It all adds to visual distraction while reading code. And we all know that most code is read many times more than it is written.

Comment: @E-Riz Well, it usually doesn't have to be done in two places because of the diamond operator and improved type inference, unless you're unlucky enough to be working with an older Java release, but you give an interesting point. I personally don't mind all that much, and think the type parameters can be handy for keeping track of types, but I suppose that's because of inexperience and because I haven't worked much with less verbose languages and/or languages with better type inference. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, you can specify the type parameter in the `List` declaration *and* the `ArrayList` constructor. So, thanks to Java "generics" you have to specify the same type in 2 places - a violation of [the](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself) [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) [principle](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don't_Repeat_Yourself).
Typed collections are useful, but there are cases where you don't care about (or even know) the types in the collection, and usage of "raw" types is perfectly valid and acceptable.

That's why I usually configure my projects in Eclipse to disable that warning. You can do so by right-clicking on the project, choosing **Properties**, and navigating to **Java Compiler** > **Errors and Warnings**. Check the box labeled *"Enable project specific settings"* and then find the **Generic Types** section where you can change this warning.

[image]

If you want to apply this setting to your entire workspace, use the *Configure Workspace Settings...* link at the top of the dialog.

I'm sure some people will disagree with my position on this, but I find the insistence that type parameters are always better to be too dogmatic and ignores the fact that there are plenty of situations where the type parameter isn't needed and just clutters the code.

Comment: thanks. that's interesting. The DRY article was a great read as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
    private static List<String> abc = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Substitute `<String>` with whatever component type you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't a best pratice to use raw type. If you want to use raw types without warning, you have to put `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` above the method.